# SQL - Calculating median without sorting

Tags: mysql, median

I have an SQL table with one column of integer values and I would like to find the median of those values *without any sorting*. I first tried finding the numbers in the table that are greater than and less than each value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.v,       
  (SELECT COUNT(d2.v)
   FROM Values d2  
   WHERE d2.v > d1.v
   ) AS greater_than,
   (SELECT COUNT(d2.v)
   FROM Values d2  
   WHERE d2.v < d1.v
   ) AS less_than
FROM Values d1
```

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed. I believe I want the values in the above table where `greater_than` and `less_than` are both equal to `num_entries / 2`, but that would only work for a table with an even number of entries. What's a good way to get the median from what I have above?

Comment: Yes I believe you need to add some sort of case work, depending on the parity of the number of entries in the table.

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`, which one is it?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to do this without sorting?

Comment: This will also not work if duplicate values are possible. Example: *[1, 1, 2]*

Comment: @waka it is `MySQL`. Sorry I have changed the tags.

Comment: @JamesZ no real reason. I am just curious as to how it could be done.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel duplicate values are possible. Hm, so I wonder if perhaps I should alter my `WHERE` conditions to include `>=` and `<=`? This would add duplicate values to the total count.

Comment: Will still not help for the example *[1, 1, 2]*.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel what if the constraint was `Values.greater_than = COUNT(*) AND Values.less_than = COUNT(*) - 1 OR Values.greater_than = COUNT(*) - 1 AND Values.less_than = COUNT(*)`. That would work for your example and for `[1, 2, 2]`

Comment: You want the middle value when arranged numerically, but without sorting? It's perverse, no?

Comment: @Strawberry it's either a puzzle or a homework. Or both. I bet on the third one :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it is an extra-credit problem. But no extra grade, only brownie points ;-)

Comment: So you are cheating for brownies :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT (MIN(v)+MAX(v))/2
FROM   (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN
                        LEAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE v <= d1.v),
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE v >= d1.v))
                           >= (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM tbl) 
                     THEN v
                END as v
        FROM    tbl d1
       ) as sub
```

The inner query is guaranteed to return 1 or 2 distinct non-`null` values among potentially many `null` values. The non-`null` values may repeat, but by taking the minimum and maximum those two values can be used to calculate the median.

NB: Don't name your table `Values`: it is a reserved word.

Comment: But `GROUP BY` will either  sort the table or use an index which is already sorted :-)

Comment: Yes unfortunately as @PaulSpiegel pointed out, a valid solution can not use any sorting.

Comment: @user6269144 Note that `DISTINCT` will also use some kind of sorting, so your original attemt would also be "invalid".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes but it is only really there for clarity. Worst case, it is removed and my final answer gives multiple "same" values for the median, which is acceptable.

Comment: I updated my answer with a version that does not use `group by`, nor `distinct`.

Comment: I think there is a rounding bug in your new solution, where if the table has an even number of values, and the median has a decimal in it, your solution rounds down.

Comment: I tried to reproduce that, but don't see that issue. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5651d, or with a float data type column and decimal values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89893/1

Answer (score 0):

Look for total numbers for greater than and less than self number that is equal to the total number of rows/2.

```
create table med(id integer);
insert into med(id) values(1);
insert into med(id) values(2);
insert into med(id) values(3);
insert into med(id) values(4);
insert into med(id) values(5);
insert into med(id) values(6);

select (MIN(count)+MAX(count))/2 from 
(select case when (select count(*) from 
med A where A.id<B.id)=(select count(*)/2 from med) OR 
(select count(*) from med A where A.id>B.id)=(select count(*)/2 
from med) then cast(B.id as float)end as count from med B) C;

 ?column? 
----------
  3.5
(1 row)
```

You need cast to convert to float, otherwise you would get 3 here.